# Regex for Finding Radioactive Elements

Tags: code-golf, regular-expression

Find the shortest regex that matches all radioactive elements and nothing else in the Periodic Table of Elements.

Radioactive Elements

```
'Technetium','Promethium','Polonium','Astatine','Radon','Francium','Radium','Actinium','Thorium','Protactinium','Uranium','Neptunium','Plutonium','Americium','Curium','Berkelium','Californium','Einsteinium','Fermium','Mendelevium','Nobelium','Lawrencium','Rutherfordium','Dubnium','Seaborgium','Bohrium','Hassium','Meitnerium','Darmstadtium','Roentgenium','Copernicium','Ununtrium','Flerovium','Ununpentium','Livermorium','Ununseptium','Ununoctium'
```

Non-radioactive Elements

```
'Hydrogen','Helium','Lithium','Beryllium','Boron','Carbon','Nitrogen','Oxygen','Fluorine','Neon','Sodium','Magnesium','Aluminium','Silicon','Phosphorus','Sulphur','Chlorine','Argon','Potassium','Calcium','Scandium','Titanium','Vanadium','Chromium','Manganese','Iron','Cobalt','Nickel','Copper','Zinc','Gallium','Germanium','Arsenic','Selenium','Bromine','Krypton','Rubidium','Strontium','Yttrium','Zirconium','Niobium','Molybdenum','Ruthenium','Rhodium','Palladium','Silver','Cadmium','Indium','Tin','Antimony','Tellurium','Iodine','Xenon','Caesium','Barium','Lanthanum','Cerium','Praseodymium','Neodymium','Samarium','Europium','Gadolinium','Terbium','Dysprosium','Holmium','Erbium','Thulium','Ytterbium','Lutetium','Hafnium','Tantalum','Tungsten','Rhenium','Osmium','Iridium','Platinum','Gold','Mercury','Thallium','Lead','Bismuth'
```

- Scored by character count in the regex.
- Use standard Perl regex (just no specialized functions).
- Assume all lower case.
- You only need to count the characters of the regex itself.

Note if you used a program to get you started and maybe post how well it did. I'll post my best attempt as an answer to get started/show an example.

Comment: Can you quote a regex standard, such as POSIX regular, POSIX extended, PCRE…? Otherwise "language agnostic" doesn't really mean much.

Comment: Sorry, I have only had to use regex in java and javascript and don't really know all the differences. The goal is to create a regex that would work in most common languages without relying on language specific feature.

Comment: There is an ongoing discussion as to [whether we want regex golf on this site](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/840/194). Please contribute.

Comment: @qw3n You could say “regular expression describing a regular language” to exclude all the language specific things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Char count 59

```
e.+[hktv]|oh?r.+m|p...?o|r.*ci|be?.i|^c?u|rad|sta|has|ct|fe
```

Found via a mix of manually selecting good parts and running [Peter Norvig's golfer](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/url/norvig.com/ipython/xkcd1313-part2.ipynb) on the remaining items.

[Regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/lG2qR9/1)

Comment: LOL accepted answer after over 2 years! Imagine that [@drjimbob's answer](/a/18128) [was the previous accepted answer](/a/47537). ***3 characters better than accepted answer!***

Comment: For pete's sake! I've had the best answer for more than a year, and then I make it even better, and then you come along and do even better and get accepted!

Answer (score 10):

**Char Count 61**

```
lon|ct|oh|^ra|...t.+i|^c?u|or.+u|r.+c.|e..+e|f.?e|^h?as|be*.i
```

<del>One</del> 3 characters better than accepted answer!

63-character solution found with [Peter Norvig's Regex golf solver.](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/norvig.com/ipython/xkcd1313-part2.ipynb?create=1) 61-character improvement found by a personal rewrite of that program in Go.

Answer (score 4):

**Char count 64**

```
^(c?u|ra|no)|e.[kht]|[^l][gecv]i|[^c]oh?[rn]iu|f.r|ac|sta|bn|has
```

Should note, used parts of qw3n solution to reduce down my solution.  Also used Peter Taylor's suggestion to trim two characters.

Comment: I have a feeling this is pretty near if not an optimal solution. Wish I'd seen that `f.r` part. :)

Comment: There's an easy 1-char saving by grouping everything anchored on `^`, and another by changing `^(u|cu|...)` into `^(c?u|...)`

Answer (score 3):

**Char count 69**

```
^u|e.[kht]|[^l][gecv]i|[^c]oh?[rn]iu|^cu|f[oe]|a[cds]t|has|nob|rad|du
```

Curium/Cerium are a pain to deal with